# linux: traceroute send operation not permitted for remote server

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, networking

When I try to traceroute to a remote ip, I get 
`send: Operation not permitted`
When I stop iptables, traceroute works fine. So, I assume I need some ip rule for send. What would that rule be?

I did find a solution here http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=112516, and I add it to my iptables, restart it, but then after a while CSF seems to block send again. Something overwrites that rule.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[Found](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/traceroute-problem-hungarian-language-file-226212.html) the solution:

> Do you have CSF installed? If yes, open the config page for CSF and search the page for traceroute. There you'll see this message:
>
> # Allow outgoing UDP ports
>
> # To allow outgoing traceroute add 33434:33523 to this list

Comment: Thank you very much! adding CSF ports to outgoing traceroute solve this issue.

Comment: Please note that in CSF you must add the port range for IPv6 as well if you want to perform a traceroute6 (UDP6_OUT)

Comment: CSF == ConfigServer Security & Firewall
    https://configserver.com/cp/csf.html

Comment: Where is the config page for CSF?

Comment: If you are using cPanel / WHM, then search for ConfigServer Security & Firewall to find the config page for CSF.